# $rootScope:infdig error when using some query parameters in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change page URL by `$windows.location.href`. I'm using theses query parameters (parameter values are encoded by `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8")`):

- number: Numeric value
- src: English characters
- path: e.g. https://127.0.0.1/callId=123456
- desc: Non-english characters

Whole url example: 
`/app/index.html#/cm/calls/save?number=23390221&src=phoneNumber&path=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FcallId%3D123456&desc=%D9%81%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84+%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B3+%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%AA%DB%8C`

When using `$windows.location.href`:

```
$window.location.href = notification.url;
```

I'm getting following error (only for first time):

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:38
    at n.$digest (angular.js:16266)
    at angular.js:12606
    at angular.js:5943
    at p (angular.js:341)
    at h (angular.js:5942)
    at f (angular.js:5910)
    at dispatch (jquery.js:4665)
    at r.handle (jquery.js:4333)
```

But in theses situations i'm not getting any error:

1. Using only `number` and `src` parameters
2. Using only digit/English characters for `path` and `desc` parameters
3. **After first time (This error only occurs if we are visiting that url for first time)**

**Note:** I did not do anything with these parameters in client-side codes yet!

Comment: You transfer too much complicated information via url, may be it is better to use `service` or as a last resort `$rootScope` for that.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, What do you mean: `You transfer too much complicated information`? Can i use `service` when i'm using `$window.location.href` for navigation?

Comment: If angular's router not use all data from this url, you can remain and change(still via `$window.location.href`) only required parts, like `number` and `src`, and rest complicated data transfer via service.